# Command failed in VS code when using R

Tags: r, windows, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, failed-installation

I have a problem with VS code: I just install R in my VS code and I run perfectly, but I have an error and I don't know to fix it. Can you tell me how to fix ? This is my image about that error. Thank you so much.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXmVT.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the R path in your settings is a directory and does not contain the name of the executable itself. Try adding the name of the executable (probably `R.exe`) to end of the `r.rterm.windows` and `r.rpath.windows` setting.